# Sklearn pipeline keep in ID column untouched

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to deploy my different pipelines all in one with features union, everything works except one problem.

In my DataFrame I have a column ID, that I want to keep untouched through all the pipeline.
I have to give it to the pipeline because I apply some one hot encode and other stuff, I cannot just merge it back at the end.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

scaler_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(col_scalar)),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])
one_hot_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(col_one_hot)),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder())
])

  full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
    ("DataFrameSelector", DataFrameSelector(immutable_col)),
    ("scaler_pipeline", scaler_pipeline),
    ("one_hot_pipeline", one_hot_pipeline),
])
```

Where my DataFrameSelector is just this:

```py
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names]
```

At the beginning of the "full_pipeline" I want to select some columns (the ID here) and just keep it without touching it.

For now I get this error

> TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ColumnTransformer` with `remainder='passthrough'` to fit transformers to selected columns and leave the other columns untouched.

```py
scaler_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])

one_hot_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder())
])

selector = ColumnTransformer([
    ('scalar', scaler_pipeline, col_scalar),
    ('one_hot', one_hot_pipeline, col_one_hot)
], remainder='passthrough')
```

Note that if you have any column other than `ID` that is not in either `immutable_col` or `col_scalar`, you will need to drop them before the fit.

Alternatively, you can create a passthrough transformer for the `ID` columns and drop the others:

```py
selector = ColumnTransformer([
    ('scalar', scaler_pipeline, col_scalar),
    ('one_hot', one_hot_pipeline, col_one_hot), 
    ('passthough', FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x, lambda x: x), ['ID'])
], remainder='drop')
```

Comment: Thanks, i think you meant to write ('one_hot', one_hot_pipeline, *col_one_hot) right ?
It seems to work but now i have this :
`ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.`
Actually i don't even want a sparse output , is there a possibility to just avoid it 
What i did until now is just return the sparse with a .toarray() for converting it to numpy array.
I think i can do a custom class with a to array . i'll try this.

Comment: Yes indeed I was mistaken. You need to use `sparse_threshold=0` as argument for `ColumnTransformer`.